# Лучший способ программы-сборщика данных

Tags: java, android

Я новичок в программировании под андроид и не могу найти решение своего вопроса.

задача состоит в следующем: делаю кастомную магнитолу с функциями бортового ПК для своего бричана на основе планшета на андроид 7.

Функцией БК является чтение последней строки лога программы torque, чтение строк из терминала с последовательным портом, и передача этих данных в виджеты KWGT.

Я смог реализовать задумку чтения последней строки лога и отправки значений в виджет, но я делал это в виде программы, используя empty activity. То есть для чтения и передачи программа должна быть запущена. Она отрабатывает один раз и всё. Обновляет данные после следующего запуска.

Как лучше реализовать и возможно ли, чтобы приложение запустилось один раз при запуске системы (например через macrodroid) и висело в памяти, скрытое от глаз, передавая данные из файла в виджеты? Или будет проще делать всю оболочку и использовать как лаунчер?

Буду признателен если направите на путь истинный.

P.S. код прикладывать не вижу смысла, так как там 200 строчек в общей сумме, и он почти работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

1. Вся логика - в сервисе, а не в активити.
2. В сервисе с к-л интервалом запрашивать нужные вам данные (что-то там и каких-то логов)
3. Сервис стартовать при старте системы, используя BroadcastReceiver: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5290164/3212712

Если не будете ОС обновлять до 8+ то вам не понадобится выводить неубиваемое уведомление в шторке о постоянно работающем сервисе.